# How to view only the events in the intellisense of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way that we see only the list of events in the intellisense list of Visual Studio ?

Is there any extension that allows this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, neither Visual Studio or the [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Smart_Completion) add-in support explicitly filtering the intellisense list.

There is a Visual Studio add-in, [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/features/feature-code-understanding.asp), which enables filtering by events (as well as properties, methods, etc.)